# I have to make a function which adds the fractions

Tags: python

I am kind of new to python lists

```
def sum_fractions(lst):
  for i in range(len(lst)):
    i+=1
    s=lst[i][0]/lst[i][1]+lst[i][0]/lst[i][1]
    ss=round(s)
  return ss
sum_fractions([[11, 2], [3, 4], [5, 4], [21, 11], [12, 6]])
```

the desired result should be like this

```
sum_fractions([[11, 2], [3, 4], [5, 4], [21, 11], [12, 6]]) ➞ 11
```

> error: list index out of range
> actually, I have to go through all lists in a  2d list and first divide the first element of the list with the second and then add it to the fraction of another lists

Comment: The `i` value is going out of range because you are incrementing it in the first line.

Comment: Why should the result be 11? It's really 251/22.

Comment: @ShambhavGautam There is no desired list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code implementation has several problems:

1. You haven't initialized `ss` to 0
2. You don't need to increment `i` inside the loop again. `range(len(lst)` does this for internally.
3. You don't need to round at each iteration if you want the output to be `11`. Use `round` only while returning the output.
4. Additionally, it is not clear why you are adding the fractions twice.

The correct implementation would be:

```
def sum_fractions(lst):
    ss = 0
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        s=lst[i][0]/lst[i][1]
        ss+=s
    return round(ss)

lst = [[11, 2], [3, 4], [5, 4], [21, 11], [12, 6]]
res = sum_fractions(lst)
print(res)
```

As suggested by others, you can modify the function to directly iterate over elements and not index.

```
def sum_fractions_0(lst):
    ss = 0
    for l in lst:
        ss += l[0]/l[1]
    return round(ss)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike other languages, you don't need the i (index) to go through the list, you can do simply:

```
for item in lst:
```

In your cas, in each loop cycle, item will be one of the sub lists, so you can access item[0] and item [1]

Comment: ok so how would we add the fractions of second sublist. i mean how would we mention that

Answer (score 0):

`for i in range` will increment the value of i automatically. You do not need to do that. Because of that you are getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
total_sum = [(i[0]/i[1]) for i in [[11, 2], [3, 4], [5, 4], [21, 11], [12, 6]]]
print(sum(total_sum))
```

Answer (score 0):

The list out of range is due to where you pass a list with length of 6 and the for loop runs from 0 to 5. but you are incrementing the value of **i** inside the loop when i value becomes 5 in the loop. and you are again incrementing it so the **i** value becomes 6. now the it is out of range since 6 is not present in the list.

Comment: actually i incremented (i) just to check, even if i remove that line it shows the wrong answer 4. and the answer should be 11 (after calculations)

Answer (score 0):

[Krishna Chaurasia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66087782/1431750) has some good pointers for how you should be doing list iterations.

Since none of the other answers have provided a simplified solution, I'm adding this:

```py
fracs = [[11, 2], [3, 4], [5, 4], [21, 11], [12, 6]]
round(sum(x / y for x, y in fracs))
# 11
```

```py
def sum_fractions(lst)
    return round(sum(x / y for x, y in lst))
```

What that does:

- `for x, y in lst` will iterate over each element in your list. And then uses "tuple assignment" to split those pairs into `x` and `y`.
- `sum(...)` uses the [built-in `sum()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum). The expression inside is a generator expression.

  - The [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) version of the sum part would be: `sum([x / y for x, y in fracs])`
- And then `round()` as you have.

Btw, if you want the "sum of the rounded fractions" and not "rounded sum of the fractions", then change it to `sum(round(x / y) for x, y in fracs)` which gives `12`.

Comment: ok your code is giving result but after making a little bit changes, still your answer was helpful and got to know new thing. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_fractions(fractionList):
    sum=0
    for numerator,denominator in fractionList:
         sum+=numerator/denominator
    return int(sum)
print(sum_fractions([[11, 2], [3, 4], [5, 4], [21, 11], [12, 6]]))
print(sum_fractions([[11, 2], [3, 4], [5, 4], [21, 11], [12, 6]])==11)
```